# Reading a binary file and interpret as integers

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to interpret a binary file as a series of integers and read the values to a vector.
However, the line ***ifs >> n;*** always returns 0 and eof is always false, the file position is not updated.
If I change the type to char it works but that is not what want to achieve.
How can I make the code work as I want?

```
int readAsNumber(const char* fileName, vector <int> &content)
{
    ifstream ifs;
    int n;

    ifs.open(fileName, ifstream::in | ifstream::binary);
    while (ifs.eof() == false)   // Never terminates 
    {
        ifs >> n;               // Always sets n = 0
        content.push_back(n);   // Saves 0
    }
    ifs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All files are binary. Also, that `binary` flag when opening doesn't do what you think it does. Streams still do formatted, textual IO.

Comment: Read about why you should not use `eof()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: while (ifs >> n)
  content.push_back(n);
immediately terminates the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input operator `>>` reads and interprets the input as *text*.

If the file contains raw binary data you need to [read](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) as raw data as well:

```
int value;
while (ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof value))
    content.push_back(value);
```

Remember that storing raw binary data like this is not portable, and is really not recommended.